# asp.net c# FindControl inside Reapater inside HTML table return null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater inside the HTML table the problem is I'm trying to get label value on item date bound event  but it always returns null I tried to use the same code without the HTML table its working fine
so is there a way to get value while I'm using an HTML table

```
 <table  class="table table-responsive">
                                    <asp:Repeater  ID="DtImages" OnItemDataBound="DtImages_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Image</th>
                                                  
                                                    <th>update</th>

                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="cart_product_img">
                                                        <img src='<%#"../../../Images/Shoping/"+ Eval("Image") %>' />

                                                    </td>

                                                    <td class="price">
                                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="btninImage" OnClick="PinImage_Click" CommandName="PinImage" ImageUrl="~/img/web/pinn.png" runat="server" />
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="qty">
                                                        <div class="qty-btn d-flex">
                                                            <div class="quantity">
                                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="UpdateImg" OnClick="UpdateImg_Click" CommandName="UpdateImage" ImageUrl="~/img/web/upload.png" runat="server" />
                                                                <asp:Label ID="lblProId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProID") %>' ></asp:Label>
                                                          
                                                            </div>

                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>

                                            </tbody>

                                        </ItemTemplate>

                                    </asp:Repeater>
                                </table>
```

code behind

```
             protected void DtImages_ItemDataBound(object sender,RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {

                        Label Pinned =(Label) e.Item.FindControl("lblProId")  ;// its return null
                // some codes

        }
```

Comment: You have a typo :  control `lblProId` vs `.Item.FindControl("blProId")`

Comment: sorry it was mistake while coping the code

Comment: Has your DtImages Repeater added data to the DataSource?

Comment: Set a break point and inspect the controls collection n `e.Item`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the repeater data bind triggers, headers, alternating rows, and a data row all are feed to that routine.

So, you have to do this:

```
    protected void DtImages_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) |
            (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
        {
            Label Pinned = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblProId");                
        }
    }
```